# Node.js asynchronous video conversion slow

Tags: video, node.js, asynchronous, ffmpeg

I wrote a little website/service, which can download a video from a website (currently Youtube) and converts it on the fly to an mp3 file and sends this file back as the response.

For example, you when you request http://localhost:8000/v=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhoewflkQu0, then it will download this video and response the audio layer encoded in MP3.

This all works very well, my problem is that this is very slow and I can't figure out why.

---

Simplified the script behaves like this:

Download the video and write it to the stdin of ffmpeg, and the stdout goes to the response.
Video (MP4, FLV) -> FFMPEG -> MP3

I used curl to figure out how fast the script is:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/v=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhoewflkQu0
```

I get only about 5-10k.

So why is this so slow?

1. The server, from which I am downloading the video is slow.
2. The conversion is slow (because of a slow CPU).
3. The data transfer between node.js -> FFMPEG is slow.

I tried to download the video in a normal download manager, and i got about 320k, which is my normal download speed, so the first point isn't the bottleneck.

To point 2 and 3, I tried to write a local file to the stdin, and I got about 600k so that isn't it either.

So why is my script so slow, and what can I do to make it faster?

https://gist.github.com/1304637

Thanks in advance.

Comment: conversion in javascript would be slow. If your using C for the conversion then it should be faster. Your web server may have a slow out going transfer rate compared to other larger servers.

Comment: the conversion is done using ffmpeg, I'm just feeding it with the data using js.

Comment: Well I believe the conversation is slow and is capping the speed. Try to benchmark the conversation to see if that's the problem or not.

Comment: I have the same problem, you have a solution since ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I updated to the latest version of ffmpeg and that fixed it (v.3.2.1 as of Dec 2016)